# mvc 4 linq inner join unable to bind list to model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my view model.

```
public class MyViewModel
    {
        public string upld_documentname { get; set; }
        public uploadtbl upload_document { get; set; }
        public List<uploadtbl > Upload_List { get; set; }
    }
```

uploadtbl contains many fields like document_id,created_by,client_id,emp_id,empcitizen_id etc.
This is my query.

```
 public List<uploadtbl> getclientinfo(int client_id, int emp_id, int empcitizen_id)
        {
           List<uploadtbl > tm= (from c in db.uploadtbl  where (c.upld_clientid == client_id && c.upld_employeeid == emp_id) select c).toList()
            return tm;
        }
```

Here uploadtbl contains document_id which is foreign key. Now my query returns document_id but i want to display document_name which is in other table. Is it possible to do here because finally i am binding query result to model.Upload_List(from viewmodel). i wrote inner join, query returns document_name but i am unable to bind it for  model.Upload_List. Do i need to change my viewmodel?  Please suggest. Thanks in advance. 
Something like this i tried.

```
public IEnumerable<MyViewModel> getclientinfo(int client_id, int emp_id, int empcitizen_id)
        {
            var uu = (from c in db.uploadtbl join doc in db.doc_type on c.upld_docid equals doc.doc_typeid where (((c.upld_clientid == client_id && c.upld_employeeid == emp_id && empcitizen_id == 0) || (c.upld_clientid == client_id && c.upld_empcitizenid == empcitizen_id && emp_id == 0)) || (client_id == 0 && emp_id == 0 && c.upld_empcitizenid == empcitizen_id)) && c.upld_doc_delstatus == 0 select new { doc.doctype_name, c.upld_docnumber, c.upld_docexpirydate });
            return uu.AsEnumerable;

        }
```

but here  return uu.AsEnumerable i am getting error. Where i am missing typecast? please help me

Comment: Am i asking something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Near the end of your code, you need to create new `MyViewModel` objects instead of anonymous types. Change:

```
select new { ...
```

To:

```
select new MyViewModel { ...
```

Making sure you set the appropriate properties to the results of your LINQ.

Also, I don't think you need the `AsEnumerable` at the end.